# Why does the Null Coalesce Operator still return null?

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, null-coalescing-operator

I have this routine:

```
    try
    {
        CurrentSessionName = SelectedSession?.Name ?? "No Session Selected";
        CurrentSessionTolerance = SelectedSession?.Tolerance.ToString() ?? "N/A";
        CurrentSessionVerification = SelectedSession?.Verification.Description ?? "N/A";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var whatever = ex.GetType(); // hits here with no provided information
        Console.WriteLine("Null Reference Exception"); // ignores this
        string name = SelectedSession?.Name; // and this
    }
```

So why does it still throw a `NullReferenceException` error even if `SelectedSession` is not Null?

Comment: Are you trying to debug in Release mode? Also `SelectedSession.Tolerance` and `SelectedSession.Verification` could be null.

Comment: well `SelectedSession` wouldn't throw, because you're using the null propogation off of it.  What about `SelectedSession.Tolerance` or `SelectedSession.Verification`?

Comment: Please post your complete error + stack trace.

Comment: @FirstStep, calling `.ToString()` on null will of course throw an exception.  So will accessing a property on a null object.

Comment: There is always `null` somewhere. Just need to find it.

Comment: @FirstStep Well because it's in Release mode that's why it's jumping into the catch, and why you are seeing "Cannot evaluate expression because the code of the current method is optimized". If you are debugging, use debug mode.

Comment: I can't use `Tolerance?.ToString()` on a non string variable and the problem is in `Verification.Description`

Comment: Your question was interesting, but as it was all about NRE, it will always get closed as duplicate of the canonical question on that subject. I have changed your question so that it makes sense for the answer I provided - which Im 100% sure will help more people in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Tolerance` or `Verification` could be null and you are calling `ToString()` function on a null pointer.

You can't call `ToString()` on a null pointer.

Comment: Then why my compiler did not hit that?

Answer (score 5):

Null propagation operator is great - but it does not magically eliminate nulls.

This snippet

```
SelectedSession?.Tolerance
```

Will not error if `SelectedSession` is null, but it will propagate on so that the result of the above is null. The same applies if `SelectedSession` is *not* null, but `Tolerence` is null.

The problem is you then try to call `ToString()` on a null

```
SelectedSession?.Tolerance.ToString()
```